# Warm start in Pyomo + Xpress

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, xpress-optimizer

I'm dealing with a big optimization problem. Pyomo is used as a wrapper, xpress is used as a solver.
Every run I save the values of variables in order to load these values into variables before solving the problem again. So I want to implement a warm start.
The solver call looks like this:

```
opt = SolverFactory('xpress_direct')    
results = opt.solve(model, warmstart=True, tee=True)
```

In the tee-log I see that the problem is solved from the beginning, and my assumptions about the initial values are not taken into account.
I have two questions:

1. How to interpret tee log (I didn't find details in the documentation);
2. How to warm start if we saved the previous model and its variable values?

Comment: How exactly do you set the warmstart values? Can you share a minimal code example that reproduces the problem? Could it be that your solution is infeasible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code that illustrates how to use a warm start with the Xpress optimizer.
Note that I am not an expert in Pyomo, so there may be better ways to implement the `create_model` function but for using warmstarts you should focus on the rest of the code anyway.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import value
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

def create_model():
    """Create a model that is non-trivial to solve.
    The returned model has two variables: `x` and `s`. It also has an
    objective function that is stored in `obj`.
    """
    model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
    model.X = pyo.RangeSet(50)
    model.S = pyo.RangeSet(6)
    model.x = pyo.Var(model.X, within=pyo.Binary)
    x = model.x
    model.s = pyo.Var(model.S, bounds = (0, None))
    s = model.s
    model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=s[1] + s[2] + s[3] + s[4] + s[5] + s[6])
    model.cons = pyo.ConstraintList()

    model.cons.add(s[1] + 25*x[1] + 35*x[2] + 14*x[3] + 76*x[4] + 58*x[5] + 10*x[6] + 20*x[7]
                   + 51*x[8] + 58*x[9] + x[10] + 35*x[11] + 40*x[12] + 65*x[13] + 59*x[14] + 24*x[15]
                   + 44*x[16] + x[17] + 93*x[18] + 24*x[19] + 68*x[20] + 38*x[21] + 64*x[22] + 93*x[23]
                   + 14*x[24] + 83*x[25] + 6*x[26] + 58*x[27] + 14*x[28] + 71*x[29] + 17*x[30]
                   + 18*x[31] + 8*x[32] + 57*x[33] + 48*x[34] + 35*x[35] + 13*x[36] + 47*x[37]
                   + 46*x[38] + 8*x[39] + 82*x[40] + 51*x[41] + 49*x[42] + 85*x[43] + 66*x[44]
                   + 45*x[45] + 99*x[46] + 21*x[47] + 75*x[48] + 78*x[49] + 43*x[50] == 1116)
    model.cons.add(s[2] + 97*x[1] + 64*x[2] + 24*x[3] + 63*x[4] + 58*x[5] + 45*x[6] + 20*x[7]
                   + 71*x[8] + 32*x[9] + 7*x[10] + 28*x[11] + 77*x[12] + 95*x[13] + 96*x[14]
                   + 70*x[15] + 22*x[16] + 93*x[17] + 32*x[18] + 17*x[19] + 56*x[20] + 74*x[21]
                   + 62*x[22] + 94*x[23] + 9*x[24] + 92*x[25] + 90*x[26] + 40*x[27] + 45*x[28]
                   + 84*x[29] + 62*x[30] + 62*x[31] + 34*x[32] + 21*x[33] + 2*x[34] + 75*x[35]
                   + 42*x[36] + 75*x[37] + 29*x[38] + 4*x[39] + 64*x[40] + 80*x[41] + 17*x[42]
                   + 55*x[43] + 73*x[44] + 23*x[45] + 13*x[46] + 91*x[47] + 70*x[48] + 73*x[49]
                   + 28*x[50] == 1325)
    model.cons.add(s[3] + 95*x[1] + 71*x[2] + 19*x[3] + 15*x[4] + 66*x[5] + 76*x[6] + 4*x[7]
                   + 50*x[8] + 50*x[9] + 97*x[10] + 83*x[11] + 14*x[12] + 27*x[13] + 14*x[14]
                   + 34*x[15] + 9*x[16] + 99*x[17] + 62*x[18] + 92*x[19] + 39*x[20] + 56*x[21]
                   + 53*x[22] + 91*x[23] + 81*x[24] + 46*x[25] + 94*x[26] + 76*x[27] + 53*x[28]
                   + 58*x[29] + 23*x[30] + 15*x[31] + 63*x[32] + 2*x[33] + 31*x[34] + 55*x[35]
                   + 71*x[36] + 97*x[37] + 71*x[38] + 55*x[39] + 8*x[40] + 57*x[41] + 14*x[42]
                   + 76*x[43] + x[44] + 46*x[45] + 87*x[46] + 22*x[47] + 97*x[48] + 99*x[49] + 92*x[50]
                   == 1353)
    model.cons.add(s[4] + x[1] + 27*x[2] + 46*x[3] + 48*x[4] + 66*x[5] + 58*x[6] + 52*x[7] + 6*x[8]
                   + 14*x[9] + 26*x[10] + 55*x[11] + 61*x[12] + 60*x[13] + 3*x[14] + 33*x[15]
                   + 99*x[16] + 36*x[17] + 55*x[18] + 70*x[19] + 73*x[20] + 70*x[21] + 38*x[22]
                   + 66*x[23] + 39*x[24] + 43*x[25] + 63*x[26] + 88*x[27] + 47*x[28] + 18*x[29]
                   + 73*x[30] + 40*x[31] + 91*x[32] + 96*x[33] + 49*x[34] + 13*x[35] + 27*x[36]
                   + 22*x[37] + 71*x[38] + 99*x[39] + 66*x[40] + 57*x[41] + x[42] + 54*x[43] + 35*x[44]
                   + 52*x[45] + 66*x[46] + 26*x[47] + x[48] + 26*x[49] + 12*x[50] == 1169)
    model.cons.add(s[5] + 3*x[1] + 94*x[2] + 51*x[3] + 4*x[4] + 25*x[5] + 46*x[6] + 30*x[7]
                   + 2*x[8] + 89*x[9] + 65*x[10] + 28*x[11] + 46*x[12] + 36*x[13] + 53*x[14]
                   + 30*x[15] + 73*x[16] + 37*x[17] + 60*x[18] + 21*x[19] + 41*x[20] + 2*x[21]
                   + 21*x[22] + 93*x[23] + 82*x[24] + 16*x[25] + 97*x[26] + 75*x[27] + 50*x[28]
                   + 13*x[29] + 43*x[30] + 45*x[31] + 64*x[32] + 78*x[33] + 78*x[34] + 6*x[35]
                   + 35*x[36] + 72*x[37] + 31*x[38] + 28*x[39] + 56*x[40] + 60*x[41] + 23*x[42]
                   + 70*x[43] + 46*x[44] + 88*x[45] + 20*x[46] + 69*x[47] + 13*x[48] + 40*x[49]
                   + 73*x[50] == 1160)
    model.cons.add(s[6] + 69*x[1] + 72*x[2] + 94*x[3] + 56*x[4] + 90*x[5] + 20*x[6] + 56*x[7]
                   + 50*x[8] + 79*x[9] + 59*x[10] + 36*x[11] + 24*x[12] + 42*x[13] + 9*x[14]
                   + 29*x[15] + 68*x[16] + 10*x[17] + x[18] + 44*x[19] + 74*x[20] + 61*x[21] + 37*x[22]
                   + 71*x[23] + 63*x[24] + 44*x[25] + 77*x[26] + 57*x[27] + 46*x[28] + 51*x[29]
                   + 43*x[30] + 4*x[31] + 85*x[32] + 59*x[33] + 7*x[34] + 25*x[35] + 46*x[36] + 25*x[37]
                   + 70*x[38] + 78*x[39] + 88*x[40] + 20*x[41] + 40*x[42] + 40*x[43] + 16*x[44]
                   + 3*x[45] + 3*x[46] + 5*x[47] + 77*x[48] + 88*x[49] + 16*x[50] == 1163)

    return model

for load in [False, True]:
    model = create_model()
    opt = SolverFactory('xpress_direct')
    opt.options['MAXNODE'] = 1
    
    if not load:
        # In the first iteration just solve and store the best solution
        # found in x_start and s_start.
        print('First iteration: Solve to get a feasible solution')
        opt.solve(model, tee=True)
        print('Saving solution with objective %f' % value(model.obj))
        x_start, s_start = dict(), dict()
        for i in model.x:
            x_start[i] = model.x[i].value
        for i in model.s:
            s_start[i] = model.s[i].value
    else:
        # In the second iteration load the solution from x_start and
        # s_start and then solve. The log should show lines like
        #   User solution (_) stored.
        #   ...
        #   Its Type    BestSoln    BestBound   Sols    Add    Del     Gap     GInf   Time
        #   User solution (_) accepted: Feasible after reoptimizing with fixed globals.
        #   U           62.000000      .000000      3                    62        0      0
        # That indicate that the user solution was used and accepted.
        print('Second iteration: Solve with a warmstart')
        for i in model.x:
            model.x[i] = x_start[i]
        for i in model.s:
            model.s[i] = s_start[i]
        opt.solve(model, warmstart=True, tee=True)
```

In order to use a warmstart, you assign the warmstart value to each variable and call `solve` with `warmstart=True`. The output log displayed via `tee` will then contain lines like these:

```
User solution (_) stored.
...
User solution (_) accepted: Feasible after reoptimizing with fixed globals.
U           62.000000      .000000      3                    62        0      0
```

The first line indicates that a warmstart solution was registered with the Xpress solver. The last two lines indicate that the warmstart solution was processed and accepted. A warmstart solution is reported as a solution from the 'U' heuristic in the log.

Note that processing of warmstart solutions may be delayed until after the initial LP solve, so it may take a while before they are reported in the log.

Comment: I think you can use `x_start = model.x.extract_values()` to get a dictionary of values, and then use `model.x.set_values(x_start)` to set the values (rather than looping through the values).